# AppCenter analytics not starting for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-app-center

I try to use AppCenter for measuring crashes and telemetrics in my application.
The application is a WPF application, using .NET framework 4.7.2.

I register AppCenter the following way:

`AppCenter.Start("MY_KEY", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));`

Directly after the registration I see the following output message:

> ERROR: Failed to start service 'Analytics'; skipping it.
> Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenterException: Service type does not contain static 'Instance' property of type IAppCenterService. The service is either not an App Center service or it's unsupported on this platform or the SDK is used from a .NET standard library and the nuget was not also added to the UWP/WPF/WinForms project.
> vid Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.StartInstance(Type[] services)

I have the following NuGet versions of AppCenter installed:

- Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics: 3.4.2
- Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes: 3.4.2

Has anybody faced the same problem and knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is located and corrected.
The cause of this issue was caused by a namespace conflict, another package named Analytics.

Refering the correct namespace with full name, resolved this issue:

`AppCenter.Start("MY_KEY", typeof(Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics.Analytics), typeof(Crashes));`